# What's a traditional route data travels across the internet?

Tags: traceroute

I'm trying to get my head around traceroutes and why data travels between routers the way it does. From the research I've done I have found what seems to be a typical route (below). Would this be considered a typical route for data to travel?

Your LAN  > Tier 2 ISP (your ISP) > Tier 1 ISP (your ISP’s ISP) > Tier 2 ISP (the ISP providing internet to the domain you are requesting data from) > Webserver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the route you describe is fairly typical.

First you get into the network of your ISP, then you move "up the food chain" to a bigger network, one that your ISP pays to. Then possibly one or two other large networks, and finally back "down" to the local ISP of your destination.

There are exceptions of course (like if your destination is in a small network that's directly connected to your ISP), but in general that's pretty much it.